# Is there a way to declare @Convert directly onto the ENUM

Tags: java, jpa

I am using `@Convert(converter = CoverConverter.class)` to convert attribute value before storing it on a database and vice versa. I have to declare this annotation at each an every place where I am using a particular ENUM. Let's call it `TestENUM` for now.

But this particular ENUM is used at more than 100 places and I am not sure that other developers in my group will remember to add this annotation when they use this ENUM.

So I was wondering if there was a way that I can annotate an ENUM directly in a way that wherever it is used it will be converted before being persisted into database and vice versa when fetched from database through JPA

so example:

```
@Convert(convert = true)
public enum TestENUM {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a Converter and use the autoApply property:

> If the autoApply element is specified as true, **the persistence
>   provider must automatically apply the converter to all mapped
>   attributes of the specified target type for all entities in the
>   persistence unit** except for attributes for which conversion is
>   overridden by means of the Convert annotation (or XML equivalent).

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/Convert.html

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyEnumConverter implements Converter{

}
```